# Google Play Merchant Account developer information

Tags: google-play, merchant-account

So I was planning on releasing an paid app on Google Play Store as a private person and was therefore about to setup a Google Play Merchant Account.

The deal with the adress put an end to it though. Will my full name and home adress be visible to the buyers of the app in the reciept or in any other way?

I am fine with "company" e-mail adress and name but my personal information?

I never recieved Scarlett Johanssons home adress and phone number on the receipt when buying the Don Jon blu-ray, not even Joseph Gordon-Levitt's..

Is it me who misunderstood what is being shared when selling an app on Google Play Store?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you manage to do it?